# Will a Canadian working holiday visa be valid on a new passport?

Tags: visas, canada, working-holiday, passport-renewals

If anyone out there has an idea on this matter. I applied for a Canadian working holiday visa back in march and it was granted in April. I plan to leave in Nov 2013 time but when i applied for this visa/permit I used my current passport which has 11 months left before it expires. Does anyone know if I apply to renew my passport whether this will effect my visa/permit as on my application I used current passport details and when it comes to travel time the details will be different. But looking at my letter of entry there are no passport details or anything so as long as that's all valid then maybe it will be issued to the new current passport?

Comment: As a Kiwi going to the UK, my visa was in an old passport which expired, and I got a new passport. When at the border, I just had to present the valid passport + the old one with the visa inside it.  I'd assume the same for Canada, but someone else may provide a more conclusive answer.

Comment: yeh ive read similar things with all sorts of nationalities and countries just havnt come across british citizens going into canada to confirm.

Comment: @JonathanReez working holiday visas have always been on topic as long-term travel but not immigrating, no?

Comment: @MarkMayo I've thought they're okay but only if for less than 6 months?

Comment: @JonathanReez hmm, I didn't see that anywhere, and wasn't aware of any 6 month working holiday visas (most are 1-2 years).  I'll check meta.

Answer (score 3):

You will not have any problems. I was in a similar situation recently whereby I had a visa stamped in to my passport which has expired. At the time of renewing my passport, my old passport and the new one were stapled together.

I would continue to use this set up until the visa(s) in my old passport have expired at which point it is useless to carry the stapled old passport along.